# How to read Firebase realtime database as "string"(without Widget, streambuilder) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read firebase RTDB without using streambuilder.

Can I use the future or provider? If so, how should I approach it?

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase().reference();

class _BatteryStateReaderState extends State<BatteryStateReader> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: databaseReference.child("robot").onValue,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snap) {
        if (!snap.hasData) return Text("loading...");
        return Text(snap.data.snapshot.value["battery"].toString());
      }, 
    );
  }
}
```

firebase database:

```
{ 
  robot: {
    battery : 88
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert from Widget to String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a `Future<DataSnapshot>` instead of a stream of events, you can use the `once()` call on the `DatabaseReference`. See the FlutterFire documentation on the [`once()` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/once.html) and this snippet from the [example of that library](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database#-example-tab-):

```
database.reference().child('counter').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  print('Connected to second database and read ${snapshot.value}');
});
```